# Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf"

Tags: android, flutter

Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf".

```
 fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700

    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Comment: There can be issues with the naming conventions, so please try to change file names to lowercase and use underscore as separator and then try again with 'flutter pub get'.

Comment: Please post also the line that you get this error.

Comment: "assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf".

Comment: - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf

Comment: Would you please [edit] the question and add the project directories?